# Validation in cakephp1.3

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I used this query in model to validate the grade in capital letter

```
  'grade' => array(
                 'ruleName' => array(
                           'rule' => '/^[A-Z]{1}$/i',
                           'message'=>'You must enter the code'
                                  // extra keys like on, required, etc. go here...
                              ),
                 'ruleName2' => array(
                          'rule'=> 'isUnique',
                          'on'=> 'create',
                          'message' => 'This grade is already taken. Please choose a different one.'
                               ),
                 'ruleName3'=>array(
                          'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                           'message'=>'This field is required'
                             )
                 ),
```

but its not working,like if i give a small letter instead of capital letter ,its entering into the database.So please help me to solve this..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not really understanding the rule? Why only capital letters and if thats really necessary why then not make a strtoupper() in your save function?

But to answer I believe the role should look like this:

```
'rule' => '/^[A-Z -]+$/i'
```